# Unable to spot Memory leak issue in below code

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am very new to C++. I am facing memory leak issue in my c++ code. Please see the below mentioned piece of code, which is causing the issue.

```
void a()
{
    char buffer[10000];
    char error_msg[10000];
    char log_file[FILENAME_L] = "error_log.xml";

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(log_file,"r");
    while (fgets(buffer, 1000, f) != NULL)
    {
        if (strstr(buffer, " Description: ") != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(error_msg, buffer);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);  
    actual_error_msg = trimwhitespace(error_msg);
}
```

Can anyone please suggest on this. Do I need to use malloc instead of hardcoded size of array?

Comment: What makes you think there's memory leak here?

Comment: usage of these char buffer[10000],  char error_msg[10000];

Comment: That does not leak memory, you cannot leak memory if you didn't use `new` (or `malloc` but don't use that in C++).

Comment: They will be destroyed when the function exits, no memory leak.

Comment: How can i use malloc() and free() instead

Comment: use `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: You have misunderstood the meaning of "memory leak". This code does not leak. Also - is this C or C++? Because it looks like C to me, not C++.

Comment: @user1138143 It seems that there is an undefined behaviour if varaible  actual_error_msg  is a global variable because it will point to deleted memory.

Comment: @user1138143: You aren't "new" to C++, you aren't *using* C++. The above code is pure C. (In C++, you'd be using `std::ifstream f( log_file )` and `std::string buffer` and `std::getline( f, buffer )` and good stuff like that.) As for "how can I use malloc() and free() instead", I reply: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is undefined behaviour if variable `actual_error_msg` is a global variable and function `trimwhitespace` does not dynamically alocate memory for a copy of error_msg

```
actual_error_msg = trimwhitespace(error_msg);
```

So when the function finishes its execution pointer `actual_error_msg` will be invalid.

> Can anyone please suggest on this

I am suggesting to allocate dynamically memory for a copy of `error_msg` within function `trimwhitespace`. Or if you already do it yourself then check whether the memory is freed in time.:)

Take into account that it looks strange that `buffer` is declared with the size equal to `10000` while in the `fgets` there is used magic number 1000.

```
char buffer[10000];
//,,,
while (fgets(buffer, 1000, f) != NULL)
```

Comment: Much possible scenario. :-)

Comment: Seems that OP prefers UB over memory leak.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh  It will be funny if we both are mistaken.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow In that case, blame OP for not making his question clear enough. With the question as written currently, this is the most help we can do. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** - In the code snippet shown above, there is no memory leak.

> ***Do I need to use malloc instead of hardcoded size of array?***

I think, you got confused by the possible *underuse* of `char buffer[10000];` and `char error_msg[10000];`. These arrays are **not** allocated dynamically. Even the  arrays are not used to their fullest capacities, there is no memory leak here.

Also, as Mr. **@Vlad** metioned rightly about another *much possible* issue in your case, `actual_error_msg` being a *global*, if the `trimwhitespace()` function does not have a return value which is having a *global* scope, (i.e., stays valid after the `a()` has finished execution), it may possibly lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To avoid that, make sure, `trimwhitespace()` function is either returning <sup>(assuming return type is `char *`)</sup>

- a pointer with dynamic memory allocation (Preferred)
- base address of a `static` array. (bad practice, but will work)

---

To elaborate, from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) article about "memory leak"

> In computer science, a "memory leak" is a type of resource leak that occurs when a computer program incorrectly manages memory allocations in such a way that memory which is no longer needed is not released. ...

and

> .. Typically, a memory leak occurs because dynamically allocated memory has become unreachable. ...

When memory is being allocated by your compiler, there is no scope of memory leak, as the memory (de)allocation is managed by the compiler.

OTOH, with [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#DYNAMIC), allocation of memory is performed at *runtime*. Compiler has no information about the allocation, memory is allocated *programatically*, hence need to be *freed* programatically, also. Failing to do so leads to the "memory leak".